# Array data storage in react-native

Tags: react-native, redux

I will write a mobile game with React-Native. I will bring the web server question list and scroll through the screens for the correct answers. What method would you suggest to keep the questions? Local storage or redux? thanks for the answers.

Comment: `Redux` maybe a good choice since you've got to update questions as and when new questions are asked, right? `Local Storage` can also be used but it is not quiet applicable to your scenario!

Comment: Thank you. I will use redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-sqlite-storage

or

react-native-community/async-storage